# WPF touch application for Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-rt

I know it is possible to do a Touch Application for Windows 7 using the Surface SDK in Visual Studio 2010.
I would like to do the same thing in a Windows 8 environment but Surface is unfortunately not supported.

I do not want to build a Metro Application but I need an executable with touch support that works in Win 8.
Does anyone know if it possible to do a touch exe for windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SDK on a windows 8 machine. I'm using visual studio 2010 with the sdk on my machine. You'll need to install Xna to to make it work. And in xaml, change your windowtype from surfacewindow to window.

Comment: Thanks for your tip :-). Do you know if the executable is going to run even in another Win 8 machine without VS 2010 installed? I can't install in any pc where the program will work Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes it will work. I got it even running on a windows 7 computer, but this has given us some issues in the past. Best to use it on a win8 machine.